# CSS Positionning : container doesn't fit to its content size

Tags: css, position, containers

**HTML:**

```
<div content>
  <div post>
  <div post> 
  ...
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.post {
    margin: 0; padding: 110px 20px 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 560px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
#content {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: visible // hidden
    min-height: 250px;
}
```

When `#content` is set to `overflow:visible`, it doesn't fit to its content size i.e. each post is well displayed, but `#content` height is its min-height.

When `overflow:hidden` is set, `#content` adapts its size to its content, but the `.post`'s are cut to the `#content` metrics. `.post` contains `position:absolute` elements located outside of `.post` with negative margins.

Can `#content` fit to `.post`'s height and at the same time not cut it on the sides?

Comment: tried `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto`?

Comment: yep, but I don't want no scrollbar neither hidden content ...

Comment: Is that your real html? Because it should be `<div id="content">` and `<div class="post">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have things floated inside a container with a `min-height` property, it won't expand. You need to clear the float on `.post` and then the container will grow as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/k4t434sispho3nix/swwTn/

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this...

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/dBMxE/2/

Try inserting more or taking out `<div class="post"></div>` elements.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing container's overflow property to "auto"; it worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17807687/888367