# 100% Body Height (Content is loaded dynamically)

Tags: javascript, html, css

i like to have a background all over my website. Works fine while the content static.
While using javascript to extend the content, the body element don't grow over the scrolling area.
My question is similar to this question: [Div height 100% and expands to fit content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537838/div-height-100-and-expands-to-fit-content)

Note: I've used a lots of floats and can not make a fixed background div, because my website gets inaccessible.

Need to solve this somehow. Maybe with JS ?

```
Html, Body
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

Body {
  display: block;
  background: url('../Images/page-bgr-top.png') center top repeat-x,
              url('../Images/page-bgr-content.png') center top repeat-y;
}
```

[image]

Update: Nathan Lee answer helped me. My problem is that the scroll-bar move the background and all my all other centered content stays in position.

```
body {overflow:auto;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto;` to your body.

```
body {overflow:auto;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes wow, but now the scroll-bar move the background and all my all other centered content stays in position.

Answer (score 1):

Change `height: 100%` to `min-height: 100%;`:

```
html, body
{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

You're telling your `body` to be always as high as the window, so it actually behaves that way - not expanding to fit the height of the document. With min-height you allow that to happen

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/meyertee/Lpgwa/

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your using float, is there any reason for using float? try removing float and add `display: block;` OR `display: inline-block`?