# background-image center line up with margin: 0 auto with scroll-bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to have a centered background image vertically stretched over my website. Works perfectly while there
is no scrollbar that's move my centered image, but leave my margin: 0 auto in place. Now my content doesn't line up with my background-image.

```
Html, Body
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('../Images/page-bgr-top.png')
              center top repeat-x;
  overflow: auto;
}

Body {
  background: url('../Images/page-bgr-content.png')
              center top repeat-y;
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#Main-Page
{
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

Tried a different solution by set the `background-image` and `overflow: auto` on `#Main-Page`, too and get some nasty scrollbars right on my website.

Comment: is this site public ?

Comment: could you make a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @Samitha Hewawasam upp

Comment: There's no way of aligning the 2 as they use different values as "center". There is ways round this however. Create a `wrapper` for the entire center column, put the `background` and `margin auto` rules on that instead of body - then place your `header` etc inside that wrapper. That's the most common way to get around this.

Comment: Looking at your code you could even apply the `background` to the `#Main-Page` which is already acting as a wrapper.

Comment: @FDL tried a different solution by set the background-image and overflow: auto on #Main-Page, too and get some nasty scrollbars right on my website. Without overflow: auto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565797/100-body-height-content-is-loaded-dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with javascript. Calculate the width of the scrollbar and add it to the offset of the centered element.

Answer (score 0):

This is becuase you are adding too many css to the html and body

```
 Html, Body
        {
          /*width: 100%;*/ removed 
          height: 100%;
          background: url('../Images/page-bgr-top.png')
                      center top repeat-x;
          /*overflow: auto;*/ removed 
        }

        Body {
          background: url('../Images/page-bgr-content.png')
                      center top repeat-y;
          display: block;
          /*overflow: scroll;*/ removed 
        }

        #Main-Page
        {
          width: 900px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          height: 100%;
          display: none;
        }
```

Comment: doesn't not work while the content grows bigger than the visible area. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565797/100-body-height-content-is-loaded-dynamically

Comment: are you doing any ajax request before load page or do u using .load method ?

Comment: yepp i load the content with the .load method

Comment: where are contents ? i didn't see any

Comment: right now the website just work fully locally. just add some text and float it.